# Problem with "/" laravel message validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have problem with return correct message in laravel validation. My code:

```
public function messages(): array
{
    return [
        'regex' => "Field :attribute is must contain alphanumeric characters . : / - , or space",
    ];
}
```

Response:

```
"Field comment is must contain alphanumeric characters . : \/ - , or space"
```

How to return "/" in message?

Comment: Is the message correct? How is a `/` an alphanumeric character?

Comment: Message is correct, but response is incorrect

Comment: What is displayed instead?

Comment: I show "\/" than "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the message yet, but you can use [`HTML entity for slash`](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) to overcome this problem, as it will display a `/` correctly on the browser.

```
<?php

public function messages(): array{
    return [
        'regex' => "Field :attribute is must contain alphanumeric characters . : &#47; - , or space",
    ];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work i get "&#47;" instead "/" in my message

Comment: Where do you display the response @ThePartykOOO?

Comment: I display in API response

Comment: @ThePatrykOOO Yes but is it inside an app  or in a browser like Chrome, Firefox etc?

Comment: No i testing in my api tool Insomia

Comment: @ThePatrykOOO When you go live, it will display a slash correctly on the browser. You can test it in your localhost.